# Managing errors on post in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, httprequest

I made an application for the company that i work, the app its working and solved some problems, but the code is a mess, since i'm not a official programmer and this is my very first application. Now i'm trying to improve the code.

The problem here is that i dont know how to check if the http post was successful.

In the code below you can see that i made some error treatment but its not working properly.
For example, if the app doesnt receive the "ok" message from the server it will return a error, but if the internet isnt working it will not return the error because it will be trying forever to send the post.
I would like to always check if the post was successfull and notify the user, or show a error after a time of trying (like 2 seconds, i dont know), whats the best way to solve this?

Any other tips to improve the code are welcome.

````
    if ((_usuarioController.text.isEmpty) ||
        (_placaController.text.isEmpty) ||
        (_boxController.text.isEmpty) ||
        (dropdownValue1 == "Vehicle type")) {
      Toast.show(
        "\n  Complete all fields  \n",
        context,
        duration: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
        gravity: Toast.CENTER,
        backgroundRadius: 5.0,
      );
    } else if (_pecasList.length < 1) {
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return AlertDialog(
                title: new Text("Empty List"),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  new FlatButton(
                      child: new Text("Close"),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      }),
                ]);
          });
    } else {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: new Text("Send the items?"),
            actions: <Widget>[
              new FlatButton(
                  child: new Text("Close"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  }),
              new FlatButton(
                  child: new Text("Send"),

                  onPressed: () async {
                    Map<String, dynamic> newDados = Map(); 
                    newDados["usuario"] = _usuarioController.text.trimLeft();
                    newDados["placa"] = _placaController.text.trimLeft();
                    newDados["box"] = _boxController.text.trimLeft();
                    newDados["tipo_veiculo"] = dropdownValue1;
                    _dadosList.add(newDados);
                    print(_pecasList + _dadosList);

                    Map<String, String> headers = new Map<String, String>();
                    headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";
                    headers["Accept"] = "application/json";
                    //String str = '{"take":55, "skip":"0"}';
                    final resp = await http.post('http://' + ipServidor,
                        body: jsonEncode(_dadosList +
                            _pecasList), //+ jsonEncode(_pecasList),
                        headers: headers);

                    print(resp.statusCode);

                    _dadosList
                        .clear(); //Cleans the list
                    print(resp.body);
                    if (resp.statusCode == 200) {
                      if (resp.body == "ok") {
                        setState(() {
                          print(_pecasList);
                          _pecasList.clear();
                          _placaController.clear();
                          _boxController.clear();
                          dropdownValue1 = "Vehicle type";

                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        });
                      } else {
                        showDialog(
                            context: context,
                            builder: (BuildContext context) {
                              return AlertDialog(
                                  title: new Text(
                                      "Error"),
                                  actions: <Widget>[
                                    new FlatButton(
                                        child: new Text("Close"),
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                        }),
                                  ]);
                            });
                      }
                    } else {
                      print("communication error");
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      showDialog(
                          context: context,
                          builder: (BuildContext context) {
                            return AlertDialog(
                                title: new Text("communication error"),
                                actions: <Widget>[
                                  new FlatButton(
                                      child: new Text("Close"),
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                      }),
                                ]);
                          });
                    }
                  })
            ],
          );
        },
      );
    }
  }```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but if the internet isnt working it will not return the error because
>   it will be trying forever to send the post.

To solve that what you wanna do is to add timeout to your http calls.

```
int timeout = 10;
try {
  http.Response response = await http.post('http://' + ipServidor,
      headers: headers,
      body: jsonEncode(_dadosList + _pecasList), encoding: utf8).
      timeout(Duration(seconds: timeout));
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // do something
  } else {
    // handle it
  }
} on TimeoutException catch (e) {
  print('Timeout Error: $e');
} on SocketException catch (e) {
  print('Socket Error: $e');
} on Error catch (e) {
  print('General Error: $e');
}
```

> Any other tips to improve the code are welcome.

I suggest making a separate dart files with methods for different parts of the code that will be recurring in your app.

1) Create something like http_handler.dart that will have async methods httpPost and httpGet. Example:

```
httpGet(String url, int attempts, int timeout) async {
  var parsedJson;
  bool success = false;
  int attempt=0;
  while(!success && attempt<attempts) {
    attempt++;
    // your httpGet try catch block
    // inside of it -> if response == 200 then success = true
    // also parse your json here
    if(!success) {
      sleep(const Duration(milliseconds: 500)); //sleep a bit between attempts
    }
  } 
  return parsedJson;
}
```

2) Create something like confirm_dialog.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

enum ConfirmAction { CANCEL, ACCEPT }

    Future<ConfirmAction> ConfirmDialog(BuildContext context, String title, String content) async {
      return showDialog<ConfirmAction>(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false, // user must tap on a button to close the dialog!
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text(title),
            content: Text(content),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: Text("NO"),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop(ConfirmAction.CANCEL);
                },
              ),
              FlatButton(
                child: Text("YES"),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop(ConfirmAction.ACCEPT);
                },
              )
            ],
          );
        },
      );
    }
```

Then when you need your user to confirm or cancel an action you can use it like this:

```
  ConfirmAction action = await ConfirmDialog(context, "Dialog Title", "Dialog Content");
  if (action == ConfirmAction.ACCEPT) {
     //do something
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!
But i had a problem. I have implemented the tip 2, "Create something like confirm_dialog.dart" but when i call the function in main and confirm the action the screen turns black.
The console show error: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(26828): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(26828): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(26828): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection

Comment: You are welcome. Did you manage to solve the problem, or do you need further help?

Comment: I need help just to solve the problem with black screen after the modification you suggested.

Comment: Oh, wrote my comment before I saw your edit.
Are you calling ConfirmDialog from a stateful or a stateless widget?

Comment: I'm calling in a stateful. I realized the error occurs in the part i call a setstate to clear the fields, if i took off the clear the problem doesnt happens, so its related to this.

Comment: Hm, haven't had issue with that before. I did find [this on flutter's github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11321), is the keyboard open when the error happens?

Comment: I've created a DartPad for you with an example usage of the said confirmDialog and a stateful widget which has textFromField with a textEditingController attached. I can't recreate the error you are facing. [Take a look here](http://dartpad.dev/684b4097a833e0a1c7a676ffcfd0edfc) If that doesn't help you, then I suggest we move this discussion to chat.

Comment: The problem was a unnecessary pop(), since the code i was using before your tip had 2 pops (one to close the confirmation window and one for the dialog) and your code has a pop, i was popping 3 times but there are only 2 windows, so i removed one of them and i solved. Now i will try the other tips. If i encounter another problem i'll ask again, thanks for now.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay but today i got the time to try to add the timeout for the http and i got a error. When i put the timeout exception i get the error: "he name 'TimeoutException' isn't a type and can't be used in an on-catch clause.
Try correcting the name to match an existing class.dart(non_type_in_catch_clause)". I ahve searched for the error but didnt find anything...

Comment: No problem. Are you sure you have all the necessary imports? `import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;`

Comment: Yes, it was lacking a import, sorry for this basic error. It all worked, just one more question if you dont mind: the solution you made just tries for a very short time to send the post. I tried without a internet connection and the error apears after some milliseconds, cant i set it to try for, lets say, 3 seconds after given the error? The internet connection at the place where the app is being used is poor, so it will be good if it tries for some time.

Comment: If for example you were to turn off both WiFi and Mobile Data on the phone (android will be aware the is no connectivity) then the Socket Exception will be raised long before the timeout period has expired (it will be raised almost instantly).  I've written `if(!success) {sleep(const Duration(milliseconds: 500)); //sleep a bit between attempts}` inside the while loop. Change it to 3000,or pass it as argument to the function. PS Try it with emulator, leave WiFi and data ON, unplug Ethernet cable from your PC and then try to post/get, that will raise TimeoutException instead of SocketException.

Comment: I have tried in the emulator with the internet cable disconnected and it worked, thanks. Just one more thing to finish: how can i put a loading animation while the post its running?

Comment: I've made a simple [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/1648370e0fd48ac8d991f374ac306aef) for you to showcase both [LinearProgressIndicator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/LinearProgressIndicator-class.html) and [CircularProgressIndicator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CircularProgressIndicator-class.html). Also inside that DartPad you'll find some simple ways to control the state of your app depending what is going on with the post method.

Answer (score 0):

I have created sample project for **flutter base project**  to such thing , its highly maintainable and clean  copy the code here is the link

***https://github.com/SouravKumarPandit/flutter_base_project***

In case if you don't want the whole project structure.you can use this **package** for having clean and structured code

***https://pub.dev/packages/mvvm_flutter#-installing-tab-***